# Simple navbar/headerbar in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I just need a simple navbar on the top of my screen that says "App name". Is there anything simple?

Answer (score 0):

make a new component like i did Herder and use it like this way

```js
 <Stacks.Navigator
      initialRouteName={'init route'}
      screenOptions={{header: (props) => <Header {...props} />}}>
      
      <Stacks.screenn .../>
      ....
      </Stacks.Navigator>
```

may this help you